# Как в rustc 1.28.0 используется сравнение строковых данных в match?

Tags: rust

Продолжил изучение Rust по новой версии книги, прохожу создание игры в "угадай число"

Есть такая часть кода:

```
let guess: u32 = match guess.trim().parse() {
    Ok(num) => num,
    Err(_) => {
        println!("Enter a number, please.");
        continue;
    }
};
```

Если введено что-либо кроме числа, просто продолжить.

Как добавить сравнение со строками с условием если ввел `exit`  программа бы завершалась?

В разных версиях Rust обработка строковых данных в `match` была разной, какая текущая версия?

**Ссылки**

- https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/2018-edition/ch02-00-guessing-game-tutorial.html

Comment: [Описание существенных изменений в Rust](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/edition-guide/introduction.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что бы проверять на "exit" я бы предложил просто вставить условие перед:

```
io::stdin().read_line(&mut input).expect("Failed to read line");
let input = input.trim();

if input == "exit" {
    println!("bye");
    break; // обрываем цикл
}

let guess: u32 = match input.parse() {
    Ok(num) => num,
    Err(_) => {
        println!("Enter a number, please.");
        continue;
    }
};
```

`.trim()` пробельных символов надо сделать заранее, иначе при вводе "exit" мы будем получать еще и символ перевода строки - "exit\n".

(Вот на всякий [полная версия](http://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=82d7d542ffe0e87ce819513d51f604fd&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015), но на play.rust-lang.org ее запустить не выйдет, потому что он не поддерживает ввод с stdin.)

Если очень хочется именно через сопоставление с образцом, а не просто сравнение, то можно заменить if-ветку на:

```
match input {
    "exit" => {
        println!("bye");
        break;
    }
    _ => {}
}
```

или сокращенную iflet версию:

```
if let "exit" = input {
    println!("bye");
    break;
}
```

> В разных версиях Rust обработка строковых данных в match была разной, какая текущая версия?

Единственное, что я по этому поводу помню, это [введение в 1.26 упрощенных сопоставлений](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2018/05/10/Rust-1.26.html#nicer-match-bindings), но это касается совсем не только строк и не отключает старую семантику. Т.е. не то что бы с Rust 1.0 тут что-то ломали.

Comment: Да, как раз то что нужно, на том уровне владения Rust это рабочий вариант. Как я понял, когда читаем `guess` уже строковые данные "извлечь" не выйдет

Comment: В принципе, parse принимает строчку по неизменемой ссылке (https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.parse), так что при желании можно перенести проверку на "exit" внутрь основного сопоставления - https://gist.github.com/rust-play/a2271c70a6612c6275bc04d5e4737374 - но по мне вариант с предварительным if просто аккуратней.